# Automating execution of Python console in QGIS?

Tags: pyqgis

I want to automate the execution of Python console in QGIS. When QGIS start, Python console starts  at the same time, and Python predetermined code wants to be executed.

Currently, in order to perform this behavior, the following procedures are required.

1. Plugins -> Python Console
2. Show editor -> Open file -> Run script

By setting up shortcut ("Setting -> Configure shortcuts"), starting of Python console (1) is possible.

However, subsequent processing (2) will be manual operation.

Is there any method of automating python console execution through processing (1) and (2)?

Python version: 2.7.4 (default, Apr  6 2013, 19:54:46) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]
QGIS version: 2.0.1-Dufour

Answer (score 1):

For QGIS 2.4 (not sure about 2.0.1) you can specify a Python file if you start QGIS from the command line. Type:

```
qgis --help
```

You will see something like:

```
GIS - 2.4.0-Chugiak 'Chugiak' (exported)
QGIS is a user friendly Open Source Geographic Information System.
Usage: /usr/bin/qgis.bin [OPTION] [FILE]
  OPTION:
    ...
    [--code path]   run the given python file on load
    ...
```

So you can try:

```
qgis --code /path/to/your/script.py
```

Comment: Yeah that should be there in 2.0.  I think I might have even added it for 1.8.

Comment: Yes in 2.0 https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/commit/bfa08c5f06253b256b2